# Speed up shapely buffer

Tags: python, shapely

I have different [`shapely.LineStrings`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#linestrings) like so:
[image]

which I then [`buffer`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.buffer) to create a polygon like so:
[image]

I've played around a bit and found that buffering each line segment is **slightly** faster than [`unary_union`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.cascaded_union)-ing all the linestrings and then buffering the whole thing together. However I do need the total area of the buffered lines as a shapely polygon as I am using it for intersection detection later. So I end up having to [`unary_union`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.cascaded_union) the buffered polygons to get the overall polygon and this is taking some time (not for this particular example but for other examples with more green lines).

So is there a faster way to get the buffered polygon that I am unaware of?

Here is a reproducible example:

```
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import MultiLineString, LineString, Polygon
from shapely import ops, affinity
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import atan2, degrees
from descartes.patch import PolygonPatch

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Coords = np.array([
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 'N', 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 'BRANCH', 'N', 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 'BRANCH', 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [-0.85, -0.51, 0, 'BRANCH', 'Y', 45, 0],
        [-0.85, -0.51, 0, 'NODE', 'Y', 45, 0],
        [-1.71, -1.03, 0, 0, 'Y', 45, 0],
        [-1.66, -2.02, 0, 'BRANCH', 'Y', 45, 0],
        [-1.66, -2.02, 0, 'NODE', 'Y', 45, 0],
        [-1.60, -3.02, 0, 'BRANCH', 'Y', 45, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0.90, -0.42, 0, 'BRANCH', 'Y', 45, 0],
        [0.90, -0.42, 0, 'NODE', 'Y', 45, 0],
        [1.81, -0.84, 0, 'BRANCH', 'Y', 45, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 'BRANCH', 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0.10, -0.99, 0, 0, 'Y', 45, 0],
        [-0.69, -1.59, 0, 0, 'Y', 45, 0],
        [-0.53, -2.58, 0, 'BRANCH', 'Y', 45, 0],
        [-0.53, -2.58, 0, 'NODE', 'Y', 45, 0],
    ], dtype=object)

    for ind, coord in enumerate(Coords):
        if coord[3] == 'BRANCH':
            if (coord[0:3] == Coords[ind + 1, 0:3]).all():
                np.delete(Coords, ind, 0)

    lines = []

    j = 0
    for i in range(len(Coords)):
        if (Coords[i, 3] == 'BRANCH') or (i == (len(Coords) - 1)):
            lines.append(Coords[j:i+1].tolist())
            j = i+1

    if not lines:
        Lines = [Coords[:]]
    else:
        Lines = [line for line in lines if len(line) > 1]

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    patches = []
    lines = []
    Vs = []
    all_r_lines = []
    texts = []


    for num, line in enumerate(Lines):
        line = np.asarray(line, dtype=object)
        num_coords = line[:, 0:2]
        cumm = 0

        indi_coords = []

        for i, joint in enumerate(line):

            if joint[4] == 'Y' and joint[3] != 'BRANCH':

                """ --------------- BODY -------------------------------- """
                indi_coords.append((joint[0], joint[1]))

                new_coords = ((line[i+1][0]), (line[i+1][1]))
                angle = degrees(atan2(
                    (new_coords[1] - joint[1]),
                    (new_coords[0] - joint[0])
                ))

                if cumm > 0:
                    Lines[num][i][6] = cumm

                cumm += 1

            else:
                indi_coords.append((joint[0], joint[1]))
                cumm = 0

        lines.append(np.asarray(indi_coords))

    linestring = MultiLineString(lines)

    for num, line_coords in reversed(list(enumerate(Lines))):
        for i, joint in reversed(list(enumerate(line_coords))):

            if joint[4] == 'Y' and i < (len(Coords)-1) and joint[3] != 'BRANCH':

                if joint[6] > 0:
                    """ --------------- PATCH -------------------------------- """
                    lineA = LineString([(joint[0], joint[1]),
                                        ((line_coords[i+1][0]), (line_coords[i+1][1]))])
                    left_line = affinity.rotate(
                        lineA, joint[5]/2, (joint[0], joint[1]))
                    rigt_line = affinity.rotate(
                        lineA, -joint[5]/2, (joint[0], joint[1]))

                    try:
                        Vs[-1] = ops.unary_union([MultiLineString(
                            [lineA, left_line, rigt_line])] + all_r_lines[-1])
                    except:
                        Vs.append(MultiLineString([lineA, left_line, rigt_line]))

                    """ --------------- ANGLE LINES -------------------------------- """

                    rotate_angle = line_coords[i-1][5]/2
                    r_lines = [affinity.rotate(
                        Vs[-1],
                        j,
                        (line_coords[i-1][0], line_coords[i-1][1])
                    ) for j in np.linspace(-rotate_angle, rotate_angle, num=3)
                    ]

                    all_r_lines += [r_lines]

                    Vs[-1] = ops.unary_union([Vs[-1]] + r_lines)

                else:
                    """ --------------- PATCH -------------------------------- """
                    lineA = LineString([(joint[0], joint[1]),
                                        ((line_coords[i+1][0]), (line_coords[i+1][1]))])
                    left_line = affinity.rotate(
                        lineA, joint[5]/2, (joint[0], joint[1]))
                    rigt_line = affinity.rotate(
                        lineA, -joint[5]/2, (joint[0], joint[1]))

                    Vs.append(MultiLineString([lineA, left_line, rigt_line]))

                    all_r_lines = []

    all_lines = Vs

    a = ops.unary_union(all_lines)

    creature = (Vs + [a] + [linestring])

    polies = []
    for l in creature:
        polies.append(Polygon(l.buffer(0.5)))

    creature_poly = ops.unary_union(polies)
    creature_patch = PolygonPatch(creature_poly, fc='BLUE', alpha=0.1)

    absorbA = creature_poly
    moves = Vs

    for c_l in linestring:
        x, y = c_l.xy
        ax.plot(x, y)

    for m in all_lines:
        for line in m:
            x, y = line.xy
            ax.plot(x, y, 'g--', alpha=0.25)

    ax.axis('equal')

    ax.add_patch(creature_patch)

    ax.axis('equal')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Interesting question but the code contains too much irrelevant stuff in my opinion. Could you provide a [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)? Or, instead, you could also post the full code on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, which I think would be a better option. If you do so, please, delete this copy of the question.

Comment: Have moved it over. I am exploring some other methods which I might post here so I'll leave the question for now

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried shapelys cascaded_union?

```
    polygons = [Point(i, 0).buffer(0.7) for i in range(5)]

    cascaded_union(polygons)
```

or in your case Line instead of Point?

https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.cascaded_union

Comment: Yes I have used this however it takes slightly longer than doing the lines one by one

Comment: hmm, but with this approach you are still buffering the lines one by one and then making a union of those polygons. Without union you can't have all the lines in a single piece of geometry (be carefull with different geometry types turning into geometry collection).

Comment: Yes, that is my problem. If there was some way to get the outline of the final "patch" without having to combine them all and without some sort of image processing

Comment: If lines are touching each other you can first maybe dissolve them so you get one big line and then try the buffer? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/150001

Comment: I don't believe that is the problem here. When buffering shapely must meld together overlapping sections and I think that is where the bulk of the computation is being done

Comment: I don't think so, every buffer is instance for itself, I hope someone else replies cause I'm interested now too :D